# About android query contentprovider

Tags: android

I want to use quick search box(qsb). But I meet some problems here,

```
    @Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String s2 = strFileName + " like '"+selectionArgs[0]+"%'";
    Cursor  cursor = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(strTableName, 
                           projection, s2, null, null, null, sortOrder);
    Log.i("QQQQQQQQQQ",String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
    return cursor;
}
```

The question is I always get one search result(show in the search listview); however, the log information shows the result is larger than 1. Are there anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: By the way, I extend the contentProvider!

Comment: we need know the data how to bind to the listview? or, you can check this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html

Comment: I finally find out where is the problem. I should provide the column    SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID  as well.